# In Grails, is "property" a reserved word?

Tags: grails

In Grails, is "property" a reserved word? That is, can I name a domain class `Property` and have its owner reference it by `properties`? Example:

```
class Thing {
    static hasMany = [properties: Property]
}

class Property {
    static belongsTo = [thing: Thing]
}
```

When I try to add a `Property` to a `Thing` I get the error:

```
Exception thrown: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.DataBindingLazyMetaPropertyMap.add() is applicable for argument types: (Property) values: [Property : null]

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.DataBindingLazyMetaPropertyMap.add() is applicable for argument types: (Property) values: [Property : null]

    at ConsoleScript10.run(ConsoleScript10:3)
```

Is there a list of all Grails reserved words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that `Property` is reserved, but `properties` is treated specially for domain classes since it's used for [data binding](http://grails.org/Controllers+-+Data+Binding). What happens when you change:

```
static hasMany = [properties: Property]
```

to something like

```
static hasMany = [myProperties: Property]
```

Answer (score 0):

Grails is a web framework. In general, only languages really have reserved words. The reserved words of Groovy are all those reserved by Java, plus a few others. The complete list is shown [here](http://docs.huihoo.com/groovy/groovy-1.0-b7-reference-card.pdf).

You'll notice that it does include "property", which was a big surprise to me, as I've no idea what it's used for, and I think/thought I know Groovy reasonably well. Perhaps it's reserved for future use?

Answer (score -1):

While I cant [find any file with the name `Property` in grails](http://fisheye.codehaus.org/search/grails/?comment=&contents=&addedText=&deletedText=&filename=**/Property.*&branch=&tag=&fromdate=&todate=&groupby=file&col=path&col=revision&col=author&col=date&col=csid&refresh=y), it is wise not to use such a common word - who knows when it might become reserved in the future?

What would happen if you just prepended your classname with something, like BlahProperty?